# PHP Manage/Add Virtualhost

Tags: php, dns, virtualhost

Is there a free PHP script that allows you to easily add a virtualhost?

I need to do this, because I'll be opening a free forum host, and want to allow users to use their own domain, aside from a free subdomain.

Comment: Would you really want a script to be able to restart your webserver based on user input? No biggie having PHP generate the `<virtualhost>` text itself, but having the script bounce the server? That's scary.

Comment: Maybe a script to park the domain would be better? Would that be possible? So, if a user pointed their domain to my nameservers, and they parked their domain, it'd point the domain to the correct directory.

Comment: If controlled creation of virtual hosts isnt really a problem. All depends how much freedom you give to client to this generation process. Actually I also would not mind such library.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting the server whenever you add a new domain to it could be problematic. If there was ever a problem writing the file, you lose all the sites, and if there is data cached (I'm thinking mainly about [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC)), you also lose the usefulness of the cache.

Having the default virtual host handle the new domains, and then having the PHP code acting according to $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] would be a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to wildcard all domains to a set directory then there use mod rewrite to map the specific domains to specific directories or in the case of say a MU wordpress install you can use the domain to map to a user account.

you can edit the .htaccess file on the fly without restarting apache.

Answer (score 0):

couldnt php create a vhost file which is included in the main vhost handle this?
using cron to determine weather there has been updates to the attached vhost you could reload apache